# Using requests module to consume API?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have created an API with some endpoints like:

```
www.domain.com/api/items
www.domain.com/api/items/1
www.domain.com/api/items/available
```

Now I want to be able to do those same queries from my views to populate my HTML.
I've been reading that you can do it using:

```
requests.get('localhost/api/items')
```

But I'm wondering if there is a way of doing it internally, like maybe calling the viewset directly, or something similar.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the [Django testing tools documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is straightforward using the [Django testing tools](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/).

```
>>> from django.test import Client
>>> c = Client()
>>> response = c.post('/api/items')
>>> response.status_code
200
>>> response.content
<response html here>
```

Note that no HTTP requests are actually sent when using the test client. As stated in the Django docs:

> The test client is a Python class that acts as a dummy Web browser, allowing you to test your views and interact with your Django-powered application programmatically.

You can prepare unit tests using these tools in Django using [essentially the same sematics](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/overview/) as the standard [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unittest.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

Based on purpose why do you need to call this internal view?

Probably you want to run (reuse) already existing code

In general, it would be better to move out view code into some manager's function and then run new function in both views.